# Prove the inequality $(n-2k)^{2x}[2x+m(n-2k)]<2n^{2x}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that, for sufficiently large $x$, the following equality holds.

$(n-2k)^{2x}[2x+ m(n-2k)]<2n^{2x}$

Where $n,m,k,x$ are positive integers and $0< k<n$. I've tried induction, defining a function $f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{LHS}}{\mathrm{RHS}}$ and finding its derivative but none of these attempts have worked.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{N}^0$ ?

Comment: Natural numbers including $0$. But for all intents and purposes, they're positive integers since I'm only really interested in large values of the constants.

Comment: If $0 < 2k < n$, put $A = (n/(n - 2k))^2 > 1$. For increasing $x$, the exponential factor $A^x$ will eventually exceed the linear factor $x + \tfrac{1}{2} + \pi{m}(n - 2k)$.

Comment: Edited the question to cut out the fluff and cut out the trivial case when $k=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to my own question a year later, we can take logarithms of both sides to get $$2\ln(n-2k)x+\ln[2x+ m(n-2k)]<2\ln(n)x+\ln(2)\\$$

Since $\text{LHS}\sim2\ln(n-2k)x$ but $\text{RHS }
\sim2\ln(n)x$, the inequality holds for sufficiently large $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=0$ then we get that $n^{2x} (2x+1+2\pi m n ) <2 n^{2x}$ divide by $n^{2x}$ assuming $n\not=0$ , we get that $2x+1+2\pi m n <2$ which is true just when $x=0$ and $n=0$ or $m=0$, so obviously its false.

I think you have to make $k$ strictly bigger than $0$, for it to work (not sure).

**Edit** : now i am sure, the inequality will be true for all sufficiently large $x$ if $k$ is strictly bigger than $0$, no matter what are the values for the other variables.